# What is the linux equivalent of altering a .inf file?

Tags: linux, drivers, inf, ftdi

I am using an FTDI USB to UART breakout bridge. It has an inbuilt timer, the Receive Buffer Latency Timer, that starts timing when a piece of data is received to a buffer and on timeout then sends data. This timeout is set as a default to 16 milliseconds.

The documentation states that when using Windows and D2XX drivers this timeout can be altered by changing the value in the `ftdiport.inf` file as follows:

```
[FtdiPort.NT.HW.AddReg]
HKR,,"LatencyTimer",0x00010001,16
```

I am instead using Linux and reading values from a VCP (using `/dev/ttyUSB0)`. How would I access and change the equivalent of the .inf variables that I would find in this set-up?

Should I instead be writing directly to registers on the micro-controller? If so how do I differentiate between registers on the bridge and registers on the sensor I am using the bridge to connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the
[setserial command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setserial).

This command gives you much less control than does the `.inf` file:

```
setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 low_latency
```

For a more exact setting, you might be able to set the
[FTDI Latency Timer](https://projectgus.com/2011/10/notes-on-ftdi-latency-with-arduino/)
(if it is not locked against updates):

```
#cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
16
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
# cat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/latency_timer
1
```

This will lower the timer from 16ms to 1ms (the minimum), to reduce latency.